# Get the first element from a displayed page part on a webview

Tags: javascript, android

Help me for getting the first element of the displayed view(part of a large html file currently displayed on the screen) on a webview. Is there any js methods that we can use using `loadUrl()` method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps after url page complete you can call a js function and send element name to activity?

Comment: Please help me with that too. Which js should i inject to get the displayed view element? I was totally stuck here.

Comment: document.body.children[0];

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer. How can i save the returned first element data as a string on my java class.

Comment: I was able to get the whole content of the html using this line   wv.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML);");  But how do i get the id of the displayed topmost div?